# \ref returns both caption name and numbering

Tags: cross-referencing

`\ref{key}` returns caption name (as configured using `\captionsetup`) and numbering as `\autoref{key}` do. How can I return only numbering?

Here is my preamble with main packages and `\captionsetup`. For instance, I get using `\ref{key}` after compiling is "FIGURA 1.1" instead "1.1". In another document with almost the same preamble, I get the expected result.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\usepackage{tabto} 
\usepackage{extsizes} 
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{chemformula} 
\usepackage{chemarrow} 
\usepackage{shadow} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\usepackage{chemmacros} 
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage{floatrow} 
\usepackage{tabu} 
\usepackage{subfiles} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{chemstyle} 
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{cancel} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadows} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{table/search path={data}} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{caption}

\newfontfamily\MProBoldCn[Mapping=tex-text, Numbers=Lining]{Minion Pro Bold Cond}
\newfontfamily\MProBoldCnIt[Mapping=tex-text, Numbers=Lining]{Minion Bold Condensed Italic}
\newfontfamily\RokkirrBold[Mapping=tex-text, Numbers=Lining]{Rokkitt}
\newfontfamily\AcuminPro[Mapping=tex-text, Numbers=Lining]{Acumin Pro}

\DeclareCaptionFont{rok}{\RokkirrBold}
\DeclareCaptionFont{acuminP}{\AcuminPro}

\definecolor{azulE1}{RGB}{0,93,171}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}

    As cited in \ref{test}.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \tikz\draw[red,fill=red] (0,0) circle (.5ex);
    \caption{Figure example.}
    \label{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ and if you load any packages that affect the operation of `\label` and `\ref`. And, do tell us if you have commands such as `\let\ref\autoref` somewhere in the preamble.

Comment: Why do you have the document class after loading the packages? That does not make any sense

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired result, remove the `chemstyle` package from your preamble.

Off-topic:

- The `hyperref` package should be loaded after most of the other packages
- Don't use `[H]` as floating specifier - this is almost always a guarantee for bad placement of figures
- Your preamble looks a bit ... crowed. You should only use the packages you need for a specific document. For example are you sure you need multiple font packages which overwrite each other?

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts} 

\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\usepackage{tabto} 
\usepackage{extsizes} 
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{chemformula} 
\usepackage{chemarrow} 
\usepackage{shadow} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\usepackage{chemmacros} 
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage{floatrow} 
\usepackage{tabu} 
\usepackage{subfiles} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
%\usepackage{chemstyle} 
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{cancel} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadows} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{table/search path={data}} 
%\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 

\definecolor{azulE1}{RGB}{0,93,171}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}

    As cited in \ref{test}.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \tikz\draw[red,fill=red] (0,0) circle (.5ex);
    \caption{Figure example.}
    \label{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks samcarter for your hep and suggestions. I figured out that was in the chemstyle package. But if someone needs to use  chemstyle package and avoid such behavior should disable loading of varioref: \usepackage[varioref=false]{chemstyle}.

Comment: "Don't use [H] as floating specifier - this is almost always a grantee for bad placement of figures" -- I guess it's Word inertia that has prevailed in certain environments.